# How to get cms content via magento1.9 soap api v1

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap-api-v1

I need cms page content which has a short code in it, so it returns shortcode. It should return HTML instead of that. I need to solve this via soap API v1.Below is the output I got.

> ## page title
>
> {{block type="imagegallery/imagegallery" name="imagegallery" category_id="13" template="imagegallery/main_category_01.phtml" }}
>               {{block type="imagegallery/imagegallery" name="imagegallery" category_id="15" template="imagegallery/main_category_01.phtml" }}

```
<?php

require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$client     = new SoapClient('http://localhost/project/api/soap/?wsdl');


$user_name  = $_POST["user_name"];
$password   = $_POST["password"];
$session    = $client->login($user_name, $password);

$response = array();
$pageId   = "41";
$page_sub_contain   = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);
$page_main_contain  = $page_sub_contain->getContent();

$result   = $page_main_contain;
$response = array(
    "status" => "1",
    "message" => "suceess",
    "contain" => $result
);

ob_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');

echo json_encode($response);
exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$pageSubContain   = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);
$pageMainContain  = $pageSubContain->getContent();

/* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
$helper = Mage::helper('cms');
$processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter($pageMainContain);
$response = array(
    "status" => "1",
    "message" => "suceess",
    "contain" => $html
);
```

**[Update]**

I tested using the following code. Working fine with the fresh installation.

```
$client     = new SoapClient('http://magento1941.com:8888/api/soap/?wsdl');


$user_name  = 'admin';
$password   = 'admin123';
$session    = $client->login($user_name, $password);

$response = array();
$pageId   = "11";
$pageSubContain   = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);
$pageMainContain  = $pageSubContain->getContent();

/* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
$helper = Mage::helper('cms');
$processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter($pageMainContain);
$response = array(
    "status" => "1",
    "message" => "suceess",
    "contain" => $html
);

ob_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');

echo json_encode($response);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: It is giving me error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getPage() on a non-object".

Comment: Where you found getPage()?

Comment: in this preceding block which called by this page {{block type="imagegallery/imagegallery" name="imagegallery" category_id="13" template="imagegallery/main_category_01.phtml" }}

Comment: Show your clock code 'imagegallery/imagegallery'. Update your question with code.

Comment: You are absolutely right sir.....the second cms which is called from short code has a line as below...... which I commented ...working fine,...thank you                                                                               "<?php //$pageid = Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getId(); ?>"